# Change a file in our network trough powershell as an administrator

Tags: powershell

I try to replace some lines in .ini files on devices which are not in our Domain. I need to execute the copy/paste-item and get/set-content cmdlet's with the local administrator account. The IP's of all the devices are in a seperate text file. Could someone tell me, how I can execute my cmdlet's as the local administrator?

```
$user = ".\administrator"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user,$pass

$IP_Array = (Get-Content \\iparraypath)

foreach ($IP in $IP_Array) {
    mainreplace
}

function mainreplace {
    $path = "\\$IP\path.."
    Copy-Item $path path..

    $l = (Get-Content $path) 

    if ($l.StartsWith('oldtext')) {
        ($l) -replace "oldtext.*",'newtext' | Set-Content $path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet you're looking for is [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-3.0). Also, you want to run `-replace` on the entire content of the input file, otherwise all non-matching lines would be removed from the output.

```
foreach ($IP in $IP_Array) {
    Invoke-Command -Computer $IP -ScriptBlock {
        # use local path here, b/c the scriptblock is running on the remote host
        $file = 'C:\path\to\your.ini'
        (Get-Content $file) -replace 'oldtext.*', 'newtext' |
            Set-Content $file
    } -Credential $cred
}
```

Copying the file is not necessary (unless you want to keep a backup copy), because putting `Get-Content` in parentheses (a so-called grouping expression) reads the entire content into memory before the replacement. That way you can write the modified output directly back to the source file.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. For now I go for a workaround whith mapping the drives trough net use. I'll definetly look into your Way and try it out. Have a nice day :)